# SSRS logging a copy of every report run

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Does anyone know if it is possible to have SSRS log a PDF of every report run?  I'd like to store the output (preferrably a PDF) somewhere of every report. I need to store what was visually presented to them, not just the parameters that were passed in.

Can SSRS do this out of the box somehow?  If it can't, I'll have to log a copy via code on each call we make to the server, which I'm worried will slow down our application.  Our reports are run from front-end code calling into SSRS, if that matters.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why are you logging these pdfs? Is the data potentially changing between report runs?

Comment: Yes.  I need exact copy of what was run at that point in time.  Data could potentially change later.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its possible out of box. Its a very unique requirement.

Possible solution is to create a report which will be using ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog table to generate report of execution. Once your report is ready you can configure it to generate PDFs. You can refer to http://blogs.wrox.com/article/creating-a-report-server-usage-report-with-sql-server-reporting-services/ for creating such report.